# What causes the failure to pass props from parent to child in this React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a small React app. It has a list of buttons in a *Buttons.js* component.

Following **[this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)**, I am trying to pass the value of the label attribute into the *single button template* like this:

##### In Buttons.js:

```
import './Buttons.css';
import Button from './Button';

const Buttons = (props) => {
 return (
  <ol class="buttons-container">
   <Button label="Clik 1" />
   <Button label="Clik 2" />
   <Button label="Clik 3" />
  </ol>
 );
};

export default Buttons;
```

##### In Button.js:

```
import './Button.css';

const Button = () => {
  return ( <li>{ this.props.label }</li> );
}

export default Button;
```

#### The problem

The code above shows no error in the console, but it does throw this in the browser's console:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct code is

```js
import './Button.css';

const Button = (props) => {
  return ( <li>{ props.label }</li> );
}

export default Button;
```

You forgot to pass `props` and you were using `this.props.label`.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing Class Components and Function Components.

In a Function Component, like the one you, have props are passed as the first argument to the function.

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return ( <li>{props.label}</li> );
}
```

And commonly destructured:

```
const Button = ({label}) => {
    return ( <li>{label}</li> );
}
```

You would access props via `this` if you were writing a Class Component:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <li>{this.props.label}</li> );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Button.js you forgot to pass `props` as parameter to the functional component

`const Button = (props) => { return ( <li>{ props.label }</li> ); }`

And no need to do `this.props.label`
Replace it with `props.label`

Comment: I thought it was that, but unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: no `this` in a functional component

Comment: Edites the answer should be fixed

Comment: Yes, added in the answer what Mark Barton commented

Comment: Ok, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

First, your Button component is a functional component, so no need for `this`. Second, you need to define props in your button component;

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return ( <li>{ props.label }</li> );
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: They are called Function Components, not Functional Components. Since the introduction of hooks, Function Components rarely meet the requirements of Functional Programming.